How to Use VBA to Filter a Pivot Field (Data Model)
I am attempting to write code that will allow me to filter out a single item from a pivot field. My pivot table is built from a data model and not from a regular table. I believe this changes things. None of the online solutions I found work, and I think this is why.
Currently, I am using:
pf.VisibleItemsList = FilterArray
where pf is a custom variable for pivot field and FilterArray is a custom array with the values I want to filter for.
I don't know how to filter out one specific value though. I have tried
pi.Visible = False
where pi is a custom variable for pivot item, but it throws an error "Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class." I am only setting one item to false. There are other items in there.
I saw somewhere that this could be because of the pivot cache and that I should set the "Number of items to retain per field" to zero. However, the option to select that is greyed out for me. Again, I think this is because I am using a data model as the source of my pivot table. The option is not greyed out if I view a pivot table that has been created from regular table.
I hope someone has a work around for data model pivot tables. Thanks.


The syntax differs for the PivotTable based on the data model.

The table (ListObject) named Table1 on Sheet1. It is loaded into data model by PQ.


Sub FilterPT()
    Dim PT As PivotTable, pfRegion As PivotField, pfProduct As PivotField
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pfRegion = PT.PivotFields("[Table1].[Region].[Region]")
    pfRegion.ClearAllFilters
    PT.CubeFields(1).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pfRegion.VisibleItemsList = Array("[Table1].[Region].&[BB]", "[Table1].[Region].&[CC]")
    Set pfProduct = PT.PivotFields("[Table1].[Product].[Product]")
    pfProduct.VisibleItemsList = Array("[Table1].[Product].&[A]", "[Table1].[Product].&[B]")
End Sub



Update:

Question: if you had 20 product types and wanted to remove just one of them.

Option Explicit

Sub FilterPT()
    Dim PT As PivotTable, pfRegion As PivotField, pfProduct As PivotField
    Dim arrList, arrVis, i As Long, iR As Long
    Const HIDE_ITEMS = "|AA|CC|" ' hide AA and CC in Region
    arrList = GetItems("Region")
    If Not IsArray(arrList) Then Exit Sub
    ReDim arrVis(1 To UBound(arrList))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, HIDE_ITEMS, "|" & arrList(i) & "|", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            iR = iR + 1
            arrVis(iR) = "[Table1].[Region].&[" & arrList(i) & "]"
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrVis(1 To iR)
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set pfRegion = PT.PivotFields("[Table1].[Region].[Region]")
    pfRegion.ClearAllFilters
    PT.CubeFields(1).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pfRegion.VisibleItemsList = arrVis
End Sub

Function GetItems(ByVal ColName As String)
    Dim oConn As WorkbookConnection, oRS As Object ' Recordset
    Dim oCnn As Object, sTabName As String
    ' Set the connection to the Power Pivot Data Model
    Set oConn = ThisWorkbook.Connections(1)
    sTabName = oConn.ModelTables(1).Name ' Assumes there is only a table
    Set oCnn = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    Dim sSQL As String: sSQL = "EVALUATE DISTINCT('" & sTabName & "'[" & ColName & "])"
    oRS.Open sSQL, oCnn
    If oRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
        oRS.MoveFirst
        Dim i As Long: i = 1
        Dim arrItem
        ReDim arrItem(1 To oRS.RecordCount)
        Do While Not oRS.EOF
            arrItem(i) = oRS.Fields(0)
            i = i + 1
            oRS.MoveNext
        Loop
        GetItems = arrItem
    Else
        GetItems = ""
    End If
End Function


This post shows the basic logic of the 2nd snippet.


Thank you for your response. This code is great, but I don't think it would work if you had 20 product types and wanted to remove just one of them. You'd have to enter the 19 that you wanted in the code above right?

You don't have to use hard code. I've updated the code.
